# How to show day names,using date-histogram aggregation in elascticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been trying to use date histogram aggregation in elasticsearch and it returns the date as epoch or in yy-mm-dd-mm-ss format. But what I want is to get document count per week day like monday , tuesday etc. Is there any way in which I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go for a different approach.
Using scripts , you can convert date time into week day.
On this value if you apply terms aggregation , it should work fine.

Script to convert date time value into weekday

```
Date date = new Date(doc['created_at'].value) ; 
java.text.SimpleDateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('EEE');
format.format(date)
```

Query to get the values

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "perWeekDay": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "Date date = new Date(doc['created_at'].value) ; java.text.SimpleDateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('EEE');format.format(date)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also find some more examples on using scripting in aggregations [here](https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-scripting-aggregations).

Answer (score 8):

I may be missing something, but, isn't the answer simpler than Vineeth's answer?

```
"aggregations": {
    "timeslice": {
        "histogram": {
            "script": "doc['timestamp'].date.getHourOfDay()",
            "interval": 1,
            "min_doc_count": 0,
            "extended_bounds": {
                "min": 0,
                "max": 23
            },
            "order": {
                "_key": "desc"
            }
        }
    }
```

This is nice, as it'll also include any hours with zero results, and, it'll extend the results to cover the entire 24 hour period (due to the extended_bounds).

You can use 'getDayOfWeek', 'getHourOfDay', ... (see 'Joda time' for more).

This is great for hours, but for days / months it'll give you an number rather than the month name. To work around, you can get the timeslot as a string - **but**, this'll won't work with the extended bounds approach, so you may have empty results (i.e. [Mon, Tues, Fri, Sun]).

In-case you want that, it is here:

```
"aggregations": {
    "dayOfWeek": {
        "terms": {
            "script": "doc['timestamp'].date.dayOfWeek().getAsText()",
            "order": {
                "_term": "asc"
            }
        }
    }
```

Even if this doesn't help you, hopefully someone else will find it and benefit from it.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to use this format for the script: 

        `"script": "doc['timestamp'].date.dayOfWeek"`

Notice the missing parenthesis.

Comment: This works well.  The new syntax for Elastic 6.6 for getting the hour of the day is:  `doc['timestamp'].value.getHour()`.  Elastic already knows that `timestamp` is a date, so you can use `.value` instead of the `date` function.

Answer (score 2):

For ES5 using painless, this works:

```
"aggs": {
    "dayOfWeek": {
        "terms": {
            "script": {
                "inline": "doc['date_utc'].date.dayOfWeek",
                "lang": "painless"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, can you tell me how can we get the day of week in text format like Monday, Tuesday etc.

Comment: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html -> a script containing e.g. "doc['timestamp'].date.toString('E')" would output Mon, Tue, Wed ...

Comment: You can use e.g. "Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc.timestamp.date.millis).atZone(ZoneId.of(params.tz)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('e HH'))" and pass in any pattern from  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns

(This gives you timezone support ... etc)

Comment: this changes by the time you get to ES7 - to something closer to : 

Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc.timestamp.getValue().getMillis()).atZone(ZoneId.of(params.tz)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('E HH'))